# System identifies the dongle but doesn't let me connect to the internet

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I downloaded a tar.gz file of the dongle's driver but I don't know how to install it. I'm kind of new to Linux systems . Can someone help me please?

Using the terminal I tried going to the folder where I extracted the files from the tar.gz file and then I typed `./install` but then again there was a permission error . So I typed `chmod a+x install` . That fixed the permission error but then they say no such file or directory. Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: Did you take a look at [How to install a tar.gz or tar.bz2 file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
./configure 
make
make install
```

Might need `sudo` in there too.